# Web connector and .Net

Tags: .net, quickbooks

I'm using Web connector 2.1.0.30 and Quickbooks Pro 2013.
I'm searching for Web connector and .NET integration examples.
Where can I find it?

Thanks,
Slava

Comment: For sure with **Google** (or Bing, Yahoo, ...). SO isn't right place to ask for external (off-site) resources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the QuickBooks SDK:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads

It puts samples in:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\QBSDK13.0\samples\qbdt

Comment: Web Connector guide for those in need : https://github.com/qbwc/qbwc/wiki/Quickbooks-Web-Connector-Overview

Answer (score 0):

You can use QBPOSSDK for this specific purpose. Intuit website has some [sample codes](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0260_pos/0050_documentation/sample_code) as to how to use this SDK.